# How does jQuery.get() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and I don't understand why the examples look like this:

```
 $.get("test.php");
```

I've never seen the syntax $.get ? Why wouldn't I do something like

```
$jQuery = new JQuery();
$jQuery.get(...);
```

Comment: There's almost never a reason to write a `new jQuery()` expression, except maybe inside jQuery itself or if you're doing something really exotic.

Comment: Why would you want to create a new jQuery object when you already have `$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` symbol (equivalent to `jQuery`) is not a constructor, it's a function and an object. As such, there is no need to use `new` on it.

---

[`$('css selector').get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns an array of dom elements that the selector matched.

[`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) does an HTTP GET request

Comment: so what do I need to do before I can use $?

Comment: `$` is created by the jQuery library; it's the same as the `jQuery` function / object.

Comment: Why do you think that you have to do anything? `:P` It works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The `$` variable is created by jQuery and is the same as the `jQuery` function / object.

You're thinking of jQuery's *instance methods*, which operate on jQuery objects that contain DOM elements.

`$.get` is essentially a `static` method, since it doesn't operate on a set of DOM elements.
There would be no point in calling it on a jQuery set instance, so it is called without one instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple - jQuery *automatically* creates the variable `$` pointing at at jQuery when it's first loaded.

Hence:

```
$.get(...);
```

is example the same as:

```
jQuery.get(...);
```

If you don't want `$` to point at jQuery (perhaps because it's also being used by another library), look at [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

`$` or `jQuery` is an object, that allows you to use some methods like `get`.

The `new` keyword is usually used with a function that acts like a class. The new keyword sets  `this` to the variable name you assign it.

There is no reason why you would need another jQuery object (except when you want to use another libary, but there is [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)). All you need is in the `jQuery` object.